# How can I filter a numpy array based on another numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

I have two numpy arrays that were created by splitting one array.  X has 7 columns and Y has 1 column.

I am filtering X with :

```
X[(X[:,2] != 0) & (X[:,1] != 0) & (X[:,3] != 0) & (X[:,4] != 0)]
```

This gives me the correct rows of X.  How do I get the rows in Y with the matching row indices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the same way you get X

```
mask = (X[:,2] != 0) & (X[:,1] != 0) & (X[:,3] != 0) & (X[:,4] != 0)
# mask is a list of [True,False,True,...]
print X[mask]
print Y[mask]
```

Comment: Thanks Joran.  This was just what I needed.